# Get Process Diagram with Service Task in Activiti

Tags: java, activiti

I'm using Activiti 5.22.0. 
I use Activiti Designer plugin in Eclispe to create a process. 
Now I want to use a service task to get process diagram with current task higlighted and save it to database to show on web later.
I'm new to Activiti so I really don't know what I should to write in Java class of Service Task to get process diagram image.
Can you help me? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Activiti comes with a Diagram generator in the `org.activiti.image` module. use can use the `DefaultDiagramGenerator` for your case. below is a sample code to get you started. please inject the required services.

```
/**
 * Get Process instance diagram
 */
public InputStream getProcessDiagram(String processInstanceId) {
    ProcessInstance processInstance = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery()
            .processInstanceId(processInstanceId).singleResult();

    // null check
    if (processInstance != null) {
        // get process model
        BpmnModel model = repositoryService.getBpmnModel(processInstance.getProcessDefinitionId());

        if (model != null && model.getLocationMap().size() > 0) {
            ProcessDiagramGenerator generator = new DefaultProcessDiagramGenerator();
            return generator.generateDiagram(model, ActivitiConstants.PROCESS_INSTANCE_IMAGE_FORMAT,
                    runtimeService.getActiveActivityIds(processInstanceId));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand where is runtimeService and repositoryService. It's error.

Comment: you can @Autowire them if you are using spring :)

Comment: I tried a fews hours with this and now my only problem is I can't find ActivitiConstants in my IDE. What's it?

Comment: @Tomato use `"png"` instead of `ActivitiConstants.PROCESS_INSTANCE_IMAGE_FORMAT`